# How to set a default language on select language dialog?

Tags: nsis, multilingual

I have my `.nis` like this:

```
## Languages (first language is the default language)
!insertmacro MUI_LANGUAGE "Portuguese"
!insertmacro MUI_LANGUAGE "English"
!insertmacro MUI_LANGUAGE "French"
!insertmacro MUI_LANGUAGE "Spanish"
!insertmacro MUI_LANGUAGE "Dutch"
```

I read the manual and it says:

> first language is the default language

If I don't use `English` that works correctly, if I use `English` that is always the default language:

[image]

How I can change the default language?

Comment: I think default language is your OS GUI language if it's available

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are 3 steps involved in selecting the default language for the language picker dialog.

1. At startup NSIS tries to initialize `$Language` with the language id of the UI language [the user is using](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd318137(v=vs.85).aspx). This happens before the `.onInit` callback is called.
2. If you are using the MUI and have set the MUI_LANGDLL_REGISTRY_* defines and they are found in the registry then `$Language` is forced to that language in the `MUI_LANGDLL_DISPLAY` macro. Remove the defines if you don't want this behavior or define `MUI_LANGDLL_ALWAYSSHOW` to let the user override it.
3. The LangDLL plugin will filter out some of the languages if it thinks there is a codepage problem (in ANSI installers). This can be turned off by defining `MUI_LANGDLL_ALLLANGUAGES`.

If you want to ignore step 1 then you have to force the language on your own:

```
Function .onInit
    StrCpy $Language ${LANG_FRENCH}
    !insertmacro MUI_LANGDLL_DISPLAY
FunctionEnd
```

Comment: ...and just to complete the picture, if step 1 or something you do in .onInit fails to set $Language to a valid language id then the first language loaded in your script becomes the language actually used.